# Time Period SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I have a table like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|Id | Step                  | StartedAt     |
---------------------------------------------
| 1 | Download Data         | 10:20:00      |
| 2 | Data Quality Control  | 10:45:00      |
| 3 | Run Prediction        | 10:47:00      |
---------------------------------------------
```

What's a SQL query that tells me time per each step like this: "Download Data" took 25 minutes, "Data Quality Control" took 2 minutes etc.

Cheers.

**P.S My RDBMS is MySQL.** Is there any way to do this in MySQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`datetime` or `timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) instead of `time` to make this work across date boundaries. See comments.

#### Standard SQL for most RDBMS

Use a **window function** for this. Implemented in most notable RDBMS (except MySQL) by now:

```
SELECT *
     ,lead("StartedAt") OVER (ORDER BY "StartedAt") - "StartedAt" AS duration
FROM  tbl;
```

`lead()` retrieves the value of the *next* row according to the order in the `ORDER BY` clause. For the last row, where you have no "next" row, you get `NULL`.

I quote the [manual of PostgreSQL on window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html), since you did not name your RDBMS.

#### MySQL

In the absence of window functions, one way would be to use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.*
     ,(SELECT t2."StartedAt"
       FROM tbl t2
       WHERE t2.id > t1.id
       ORDER BY t2."StartedAt"
       LIMIT 1) - "StartedAt" AS duration
FROM  tbl t1;
```

Or this is probably faster:

```
SELECT t1."Id", t1."Step", t1."StartedAt"
      ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1."StartedAt", min(t2."StartedAt")) AS minutes
FROM   tbl t1
LEFT   JOIN tbl t2 ON t2."Id" > t1."Id"
GROUP  BY t1."Id", t1."Step", t1."StartedAt";
```

[->sqlfiddle with both queries.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99be1/12)

The manual about [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) or [`TIMEPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

If your `Id` column would be ascending without gaps, this would be simpler. But that's rarely the case in real life tables.

Comment: Wouldn't this have problems when skipping over 24:00? Unless it's a `datetime` field of course.

Comment: @wkoot: Of course, I was assuming a datetime type (`timestamp` in PostgreSQL). The whole operation would be of questionable use with `time` and no further restrictions / information. If we could assume that no duration exceeds 24 hours, a simple `CASE` statement would do the trick ...